# XDocument load multiple XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an ASP.Net webform app.
I have one fileupload in page allow multiple files.
In a foreach loop I try to read all XML the user uploaded to the folder.
The problem occurs if I read the documents. I only get the first XML in the selection. I simple use `XDocument.load(filename)` in a foreach. What did I wrong?

I fire that loop in a button click event

```
protected void btnSaveDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   //hiddenfield in page have name of xml in folder
    var filesUploaded = hfXMLuploaded.Value.ToString().Split('-');
    try
    {        
        foreach (var file in filesUploaded)
        {
            string filename = Server.MapPath("~/SFA_XML_Upload/" + file);
            var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            Response.Write(doc.ToString()); // for testing

            //SaveDataBaseMyTable(ReadMyTable(doc, filename));                
        }
```

my read method:

```
protected  List<SFA_ORDCLI> ReadOrdcli(XDocument doc, string filename)
{
    var ordcli = doc.Descendants("table")
                   .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "ordcli")
                   .Descendants("row")
                   .Select(e => e.Elements());

    List<SFA_ORDCLI> sfaOrdcliList = new List<SFA_ORDCLI>();
    foreach (var row in ordcli)
    {
        SFA_ORDCLI sfaOrdcli = new SFA_ORDCLI();
        sfaOrdcli.NomeFileXML = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        foreach (var field in row)
        {
            var name = (string)field.Attribute("name");

            switch (name)
            {
                case "RolCodEst"://key
                    sfaOrdcli.RolCodEst = (string)field;
                    break;
 ...other fields

            }
        }
        if (sfaOrdcli != null) sfaOrdcliList.Add(sfaOrdcli);
    }

    return sfaOrdcliList;

}
```

in debug i see Load method receive the files name 'name.xml'
but the response print two time the first xml read.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to see if filesUploaded contains the list of filenames you expect?

Comment: We really need to see a [mcve] to answer your question properly.  But It looks like you are writing multiple XML documents to the response stream using `Response.Write()`, but a well-formed XML document must have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  Perhaps the receiving client is only parsing the first one and ignoring the remainder?

Comment: in the fileupload if i select one file at time works well...the code read and save the xml in the table. But if i select more file i hav primary key exception because return ever the first xml in the folder

Comment: i updated the code in the question . hope this help. im going to be crazy

Comment: This needs debugging, we can't do that for you. Be clear about "receive `name.xml`", that doesn't help.

Comment: If i upload one xml and click save on db it works...if i select more files it dose not work.

Comment: With receive i mean that i pass to load method the correct path of file in fact if i upload one xml the code works...:(

Comment: Your issue is with the following line : var ordcli = doc.Descendants("table")
                   .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "ordcli")
                   .Descendants("row")
                   .Select(e => e.Elements());  You do not need ,Descendants("Table") since Row is a child of Table.

Comment: The problem is before: i commented that line to test response.write doc and it prints ever first xml in collection

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on SaveAs method:

i did fileUpload.Saveas instead of 
file.SaveAs(folderPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
where file is HttpPostedFile

sorry
bye and tks everybody